# How to draw stave music in Java?

Tags: java, oop, jfugue

I want to ask how to draw stave music and its component like key signature and others in Java Netbeans 8 with JFugue 4 Library?

Really confused. Anyone can help me or anyone have the references?
Thank you so much.

Comment: have you gone through their examples, I'm not really clear where you're stuck.. http://www.jfugue.org/examples.html

Comment: Sir, thank you for answer. I already read the books and example. JFugue cannot drawing the stave lines, the library only works with pattern. but i have to make it (stave lines music) as user interface. if i draw with canvas is that okay or not? sorry Sir, im newbie in java programming.

Comment: StackOverflow works best when you have a specific problem to ask.  If you give us nothing to work with, nothing is approximately what you will get back.  You should try to look at the examples and write some code, and then if you get stuck, show us what you've done so far.

Comment: JFugue does not provide graphical capabilities or user interface components.